# High Inference time on warmup state in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**System information**

**OS Platform and Distribution**: (Windows 10 Pro/Andriod 10,11)

**Mobile device**: (Redmi note 8)

**TensorFlow version:** 2.4

**Python version:** 3.8

**Problem:** I am working on Real time Audio processing application in android studio. I made a model using LSTMs and converted the model to the TFLITE format. After that when I tested model by giving some data it gives inconsistent inference time every time. Model inference time is 3-4ms. If I run inference in a loop, 3-4ms is the average inference time. If I shift towards the real-time scenario, I have to perform inference every 10ms. My inference time increases in this scenario. This is probably because the inference is not running back to back but actually waits till we get audio data again (10ms callback -3ms inference time = 7ms wait in thread for more audio data). I read on tensorflow site (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement) that this is due to the warmup state and steady state. For warmup state it gives 9ms inference time and on steady state it gives almost 3ms inference time. But in my case, since audio is coming continuously and I want the model to run in steady state. Is there any way to run the TFLITE model in steady state once its loaded in the application ?

**Current behavior**
Android tflite model warmup everytime when inference function is called

**Expected behavior**
Android tflite model should warmup once at start and stay in steady state after that.

**Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!**

Please find below
loadModelFile is loading function
If I use tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs); it gives high inference time i.e 13-14 ms
But when I run this line in for loop it gives me around 3-4ms inference time. Althou I have declared tflite outside the while loop.

---------------------------------- code --------------------

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("lstm.tflite");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffSets = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffSets, declaredLength);

    }
    
Interpreter tflite;
float[][][] model_output;
float[][][][] model_st;

private void foo() {
        Thread bar = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while (true) {

                    float[] data = network.getData(); // blocking call // Audiorecord is being used in the audioHandler Object // Data is returned every 10ms


                    
                    Object[] inputs = {data, states};
                    outputs.put(0, model_output);
                    outputs.put(1, model_st);

                    
                    /////////// Inference ////////////////
                    tfLiteLock.lock();
                    try {
                        tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs);
                    } finally {
                        tfLiteLock.unlock();
                    }
                    System.out.println("inference_time",""+tflite.getLastNativeInferenceDurationNanoseconds())
                    
                    //Computing 
                    //for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
                    
                    //try {
                    //  tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs);
                    //} finally {
                    //  tfLiteLock.unlock();
                    //}
                    
                    //System.out.println("inference_time",""+tflite.getLastNativeInferenceDurationNanoseconds())
                    //}
                    
                    foo.bar(model_output); 

                }
            }
        });
        bar.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        bar.start();
```

I run the model on tensorflow benchmark tool with and without delay. When I run model without any delay it gives avg 2ms time for inference. When I put 5ms delay between each inference then model inference time inreased to 6ms. Please refer to screenshots below:

[Without any delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLBKK.png)

[With 5ms delay between each inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wXRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The warmup state refers to few first runs of the same TFLite interpreter while the steady state refers to any moment after the warmup state.

In the initial runs, the TFLite interpreter might need to spend some times to allocate tensors and temporary memories for convolution optimization, which means it can take more times. After few initial runs, those configurations will be already settled done.

So, if you can re-use the TFLite interpreter object in the every run, you can assume that upcoming inferences will be done in the steady state.

Comment: In the first run, it requires more times for some initializations for memory allocations and etc. It looks like an intended behavior. After the first run, the inference time will be reduced as expected.

Comment: Yes,It should reduced in steady state. But in my case its not settling down. It keeps fluctuating between 8-13ms. although in steady state its inference time in almost 4-5 ms.

Comment: I suspect that the lock or multi threading can affect the inference time. For example, CPU cycles can be used too much for context switchings and the lock. It might be helpful to experiment with one thread and without the lock to reduce such side effects.

Comment: There is possibility that as the above loop keeps providing the same inputs over the time, this makes CPU cache optimized for the memory space of the repeated same inputs, which will not happen at the real world. If it is true, 3-4ms is not an actual inference time for the real world's use cases.

Comment: I have updated the post with new results. I run the model on tensorflow benchmark tool with and without delay. When I run model without any delay it gives avg 2ms time for inference. When I put 5ms delay between each inference then model inference time inreased to 6ms. Please refer to screenshots above.

Comment: This is quite a complicated problem. My best guess is that adding a delay usually triggers context switching and it might impact the overall inference speed.

Comment: If you want to reduce overall inference times, you can consider using model optimization techniques or/and hardware acceleration paths. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/best_practices

Comment: Thankyou Jae for your feedback but I am not able to solve the issue. Model is working fine when its run in a continuous loop (without any delay). Pipeline is, app gets voice data  and take its FFT. Then pass it to the model. Model outputs some data and I take IFFT of that data. Issue is , when there is a delay of getting microphone data, model takes long time for prediction as well. I guess model terminate itself or go on sleep. I want , model should take same time for everytime irrespective of input delay.